# CouchDB Replication does not replicate old revision documents

Tags: couchdb, replication, database-replication, revision

I'm working on "***one database per user***" system using the ***CouchDB replication***  with a selector to filter my data based on the user configuration.

It works pretty well, until the day when i noticed an issue with the replication, it is difficult for me to describe it so I will do it with an example:

I have my main database "**mainDB**" which i'm using as the "**source**" database for the replication, and i decide to create a sub database "**subDB**" for a user which will be the "**target**" for the replication.

I create my *replication doc* with my selector to filter the data from my "**mainDB**" and nothing happen, my "**subDB**" is empty, the replication state is marked as "**Running**" but **0 pending changes**.

And as soon as i **update a doc** from the "**mainDB**" (doc that is supposed to be replicated to my "**subDB**"), the "***_rev***" of this doc will change, the replication really start and replicate my doc to the "**subDB**".

In brief, CouchDB filtred replication based on a selector will not replicate any doc until we update "_rev" of each doc that is supposed to be replicated.

App version
Apache CouchDB
v. 3.2.2

**EDIT 1**
The selector looks like this:

```
{
   "selector": {
        "$or": [
            {
                "date_debut": {
                    "$lte": "#end_date#"
                },
                "typedoc": "ActiviteDocument",
                "date_fin": {
                    "$gte": "#start_date#"
                },
                "id": {
                    "$in": [
                        #array_of_integer_A#
                    ]
                }
            },
            {
                "typedoc": "IndividuDocument",
                "id": {
                    "$in": [
                       #array_of_integer_B#
                    ]
                }
            },
    (JSON too long to full parse here, but other part of the $or use same logical)
    ...

}
```

**EDIT 2** : I changed the selector logical by using $or and $and

```
"selector": {
        "$or": [
               {
                "$and": [
                    {
                        "typedoc": "ActiviteDocument"
                    },
                    {
                        "date_debut": {
                            "$lte": "#end_date#"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "date_fin": {
                            "$gte": "#statt_date#"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "id": {
                            "$in": [#array_of_integer_A#]
                        }
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "$and": [
                    {
                        "typedoc": "IndividuDocument"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": {
                            "$in": [#array_of_integer_B#]
                        }
                    }
                ]
            },
```

**EDIT 3** :  i changed my replication doc by removing selector and using "doc_ids", the replication will not replicate my docs except if i update one of them so the "_rev" change and the replication detect that and start working

```
{
  "_id": "replicationmaster-1123",
  "source": "mysource",
  "target": "mytarget",
  "doc_ids": [
    "ActiviteDocument_335765",
    "ActiviteDocument_351882",
    "ActiviteDocument_421350",
    "ActiviteDocument_423684",
    "ActiviteDocument_428304",
    "ActiviteDocument_440523",
    "ActiviteDocument_442048",
    "ActiviteDocument_443727"
  ],
  "continuous": true,
  "create_target": false,
  "owner": "admin"
}
```

**EDIT 4** : demo https://youtu.be/OqJA0fDQqy8

Comment: can you share your filter selector? In principle, replication starts from the beginning, so there should be no need to update a document for it to replicate.

Comment: Hi, Daniel, thanks for the response ! 
Here is an example of my filter selector :

 "selector": {
    "$or": [
      {
        "start": {
          "$lte": "2022-10-27"
        },
        "typedoc": "ActiviteDocument",
        "end": {
          "$gte": "2022-09-29"
        },
        "id": {
          "$in": [
            65993,
            63938,
            87265,
            312112,
            64885,
            64277
          ]
        }
      }
...

Comment: NB : my replication is "continous" perhaps that why it not starts from the beginning ?

Comment: NB2: I changed my replication to only launch once, same problem, I have two docs that are supposed to be replicated but they are not

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that in your selector JSON the `$or` parameter needs to be an array of objects, each one being an individual condition. The way you have it, this parameter is an array with a single object that has all the conditions in it.

Here is a complete replicator document based on your conditions, with the correct syntax:

```
{
  "_id": "abc12357",
  "source": "https://username:password@mycouchdb.com/db1",
  "target": "https://username:password@mycouchdb.com/db2",
  "selector": {
    "$or": [
      {
        "start": {
          "$lte": "2022-10-27"
        }
      },
      {
        "typedoc": "ActiviteDocument"
      },
      {
        "end": {
          "$gte": "2022-09-29"
        }
      },
      {
        "id": {
          "$in": [
            65993,
            63938,
            87265,
            312112,
            64885,
            64277
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: I linked just a part of my selector for the example, i can link you the full replicator file if you want but not in the comment section


Edit : https://jsoneditoronline.org/#left=cloud.ccc90b3869e04bd3bfab9e30ff3dab3f

Comment: I was wondering if there is any way to force CouchDB to full scan source database each time i create a replication doc 
I know it's not the most optimal way, but it might help my prod while i'm waiting to find a solution for my issue

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the replication. In your case the selector you have does not return any documents. If you change the selector to use what I have pasted above, it will work.

Comment: Why it return the missing docs as soon as i edit the _revision ?
If my selector is wrong, then even if i update the _revision of my doc it will never return, no ?

Comment: Also, in your example, each condition is tested with a logical OR, but in my case, it's a logical AND, the logical OR is used for typedocs
for example, for the ActiviteDocument typedoc, the start date is less AND the endd ate is greater than the given  parameter

Comment: Another proof that my selector isn't the problem, i changed my replication doc by removing selector and using "doc_ids", the replication will not replicate my docs except if i update one of them so the "_rev" change and the replication detect that and start working

https://jsoneditoronline.org/#left=cloud.3aee28b13889484f846dd15053fc6ca4